# Windows Phone 8.1 Universal app adding a new contact

Tags: javascript, html, windows-phone-8.1, winjs, win-universal-app

I have to save new contact to People app. How can I make it? Can HTML apps do something with contact storage?

I was looking for [API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.contact.aspx) but it only explain contact object. Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show the contact information to the user and then have them save it, see [this walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn518237.aspx) using the [`ContactManager.ShowContactCard`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.contactmanager.showcontactcard.aspx) method.

Comment: is there a way to use success event call back on add new contact

Comment: No, it's a `void` method so there is no return value and no event, sorry.

Comment: The documentation states, this method is not implemented for windows phone 8.1... And invoking it results in `Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))`. Since we are talking about **universal** apps here, I wonder how it is to be implemented for WP part of the project.

Comment: I figured, on WP I have to use `Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactManager` for getting all contacts and `Windows.Phone.PersonalInformation.ContactStore` for creating a new contact (without a contact card though). Is this the correct way of doing this in a universal project?